# Is there any way to implement this search and replace function?

Tags: python

If I have a video game script consisting of a mixture of code and voicelines (denoted by backticks) in Russian:

```html
d [lv 0*"19"*"11900001"]`"............Вы...`[@][lv 0*"19"*"11900002"]`снова стали злоупотреблять алкоголем, не так ли?"`[\]
lss s0_8,"nan","a1_fumu1" ;1
aspt2 xpos,s0_8,-370
flush 10,167
msgwnd_non
*d2
d `Пожилой врач, вздохнув, убрал стетоскоп.`[\]
*d3
d `В мрачном кабинете, в воздухе которого смешались пыль и тошнотворно‐приторный запах, можно было увидеть двух пожилых мужчин.`[\]
textoff
waits 167
csp_slot s0_8
lbg s0_1,"mlib_1b_bg"
lbg s0_3,"mlib_1b"
flush 24
*d4
d `В углу этой комнаты, намного более просторной, чем обычный кабинет,`[@]` стояла дорогая кровать, на которой находился человек, проходящий медицинское обследование, а рядом — его врач.`[@]`{n}Также в кабинете находился ещё один человек, походивший на слугу и молча наблюдавший за процессом.`[\]
lss s0_10,"kin","a11_defo1" ;1
aspt2 xpos,s0_10,370
flush 10,167
msgwnd_kin
*d5
d [lv 0*"01"*"11500001"]`"Спиртное — мой друг.`[@][lv 0*"01"*"11500002"]` Для меня оно не меньший друг, чем ты, да и пробыло оно со мной гораздо дольше тебя."`[\]
msgwnd_non
*d6
d `Непоколебимым тоном заявил человек, на груди которого секунду назад был стетоскоп, поправляя одежду.`[\]
lss s0_8,"nan","a1_komaru3" ;1
aspt2 xpos,s0_8,-370
flush 10,167
msgwnd_nan
*d7
```

And a text document with an English translation of the transcript, consisting solely of voicelines (also separated by backticks) and no code:

```html
`"............You've...`
`been indulging in alcohol again, haven't you?"`
`The old physician let out a sigh as he removed the stethoscope.`
`Two elderly men could be seen in the dimly lit study, which was filled with dust and a sickly sweet stench.`
`In the corner of this room, which was much larger than what most people would call a study,`
` there was an expensive‐looking bed, a man undergoing a medical examination, and the physician conducting it.`
`{n}There was also what appeared to be a servant watching over the whole scene.`
`"The bottle is my friend.`
` It is no less of a friend than you, and it has stood by my side even longer than you have."`
`The man who had bared his chest for the stethoscope spoke unapologetically as he straightened out his clothes.`
```

If the aforementioned Russian videogame script were a text file consisting of hundreds of thousands of lines of text and tens of thousands of voicelines, and I had a corresponding English transcript (also a text file) consisting solely of said voicelines, would it be possible for me to simply replace each Russian voiceline in the videogame script with its corresponding English voiceline from the transcript in an efficient way?

PS: the lines appear in the same order in both files. Hence the first Russian voiceline in backticks in the script (`"............Вы...`) corresponds to the first voiceline in the english transcript (`"............You've...`). Every nth voiceline in the first file corresponds to the nth voiceline in the second.

Comment: It is unclear how you intend to map the english translation from the russian text - are they always in the same order? Sounds like what you want is doable, but there is missing information.

Comment: @RecencyEffect Yes, they are both in the same order. The first voiceline in the translation corresponds to the first voiceline in the game script, the second the second, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be done most easily with regex and using the fact that files are iterators:

```py
import re

with open("russian.txt") as russian, open("english.txt") as english, open("new.txt", 'w') as res:
    for line in russian:
        res.write(re.sub(r"`[^`]*`", lambda match: next(english).strip(), line))
```

The pattern will match all couples of backticks and everything inside them - [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/spSljb/1).

Then the replacement is done with a function that takes the next line of the translation and thus ensuring it matches the original.

---

You might need to play a bit with the files' encodings to get it right. I was able to make it work with:

```
with open("test.txt", encoding='windows-1251') as russian, open("output.txt", encoding='utf8') as english, open("new.txt", 'w', encoding='utf8') as res:
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said both lists are in the same order, you can iterate them in parallel with `zip`:

```
result = []

for russian, english in zip(russian_list, english_list):
    result.append(some_regex.sub(english, russian))
```

You only need to work out what `some_regex` needs to be, in order to capture the first occurrence between backticks, etc.
Tip: it is easy to develop such things in the repl.

Comment: I don't understand how that answers the question. There are no lists but files and you didn't even provide the pattern... This gives no information for solving the problem presented...

Comment: It answsers "would it be possible for me to simply replace each Russian voiceline in the videogame script with its corresponding English voiceline from the transcript in an efficient way". But yes, your answer is more complete.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't really answer that because there are no lists. There are files and notice that there can be more than one backticks expression in one line in the Russian file so again - I don't see how that answers the question... What would be the `russian_list` in your answer? The lines of the file? The backticks?